# Very slow processing time / TTFB of 4-5 seconds

Tags: magento-1.9, database

The TTFB on this website I've been put in charge with is extremely slow with a custom made template and a few plugins which I've tried disabling with no luck. Using the inbuilt profiler with the Aoe_Profiler plugin, I've retrieved the following results:

[image: config/load-db slow]

It shows that `config/load-db` is taking almost the whole 4 seconds of the processing time. I'm not too savvy with Magento and was wondering if there was any way to further debug and find what specific areas of the database are causing this massive page load.

**Additional Information:**

- Disabling the modules does not do anything
- The database is reasonably large at about 90mb+ but the majority of it is in temp and log tables e.g. `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp` and so on.
- I have tried optimizing MySQL with no improvement to this slow load time.
- Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was essentially just a host problem. After swapping hosts, it's perfectly fine.